# Determining prime number

Tags: c++

Im doing exercise from the Bjarne Stroustrup book called "Programming principles and practice using c++". I have to find first n prime numbers that user wants[user enters 5, and program finds first five prime numbers]. I found the solution on this site:
http://people.ds.cam.ac.uk/nmm1/C++/Exercises/Chapter_04/ex_15.cpp

```
bool prime (vector<int> table, int number) {
for (int i = 0; i < table.size(); ++i)
    if (number%table[i] == 0) return false;
return true;
}
```

but i cant understand the test for primality. Why modulo? I have my own test for primality and its much easier to understand for me, albeit its less elegant and more verbose.

```
bool isPrime(int num) {
  for (int i = 2; i < num; i++) {
    for (int j = 0; j < num; j++) {
        if (i*j == num) {
            return false;
        }
    }
  }
  if (num == 1) {
    return false;
  }
  return true;
}
```

So if anyone can explain me that guy code i would be greatful.

Comment: Complety to check if the number is prime: O(n^2) with your algorithm. Complexity with modulo: O(n). Do you see why it is better now?

Comment: Please don't just link the other code. Copy it here so that everyone can directly see it (even when the link gets invalid).

Comment: Did you go through the main function in your posted code? Function you have posted alone does not check the prime. Go through the whole code and you will understand.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's the other code, included in its entirety:

```
#include "std_lib_facilities.h"

bool prime (vector<int> table, int number) {
    for (int i = 0; i < table.size(); ++i)
        if (number%table[i] == 0) return false;
    return true;
}

int main () {
    int count, next;
    cout << "Input the number of primes\n";
    cin >> count;
    vector<int> table;
    next = 2;
    while (table.size() < count) {
        if (prime(table,next)) table.push_back(next);
        ++next;
    }
    for (int n = 0; n < table.size(); ++n)
        cout << table[n] << " ";
    cout << endl;

    // keep_window_open();
    return 0;
}
```

This code populates the vector `table` with all the prime numbers it has found so far. Starting from 2, it checks if the number is divisible by any of the numbers in this `table` it has constructed. If it isn't divisible, it means that this number is a prime, and it gets entered into the `table`.
The modulo operator is used to check for divisibility here. `a%b` returns the remainder that occurs when the division `a/b` is performed. If this value is 0, there is no remainder, and we can conclude that a is divisible by b.

Answer (score 0):

The modulo operator returns the remainder of a division operation. So if the remainder is equal to 0 for any of the numbers in the table, then we can say that the number is evenly divisible, and therefore not prime. On the other hand, if the modulo returns anything other than 0 for all of the numbers in the table, the number is not evenly divisible, and therefore it is prime.

https://www.cprogramming.com/tutorial/modulus.html

Welcome to StackOverflow :)

Comment: maybe worth mentioning that testing for divisibility instead of brute force try all products has quite an impact on the complexity

Comment: Problem is for example 27 fails the %2 operation, yet its not a prime number. Why that test/function work then?

Comment: That's why there is the for loop, to test the elements in the table once. In your case, you test for each element in the table all the table again, so n^2 complexity.

Comment: @PiotrBurzała %2 is only the first iteration of the loop, already in the next `27%3 == 0` and the function returns `false`. Your snippet is incomplete btw, one has to prepare the `table` accordingly